# How to pull data from a table using wpdb?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wpdb

I create a new db connection with: $mydb = new wpdb (*db info*)

I know it connects but for some reason I am unable to get any data from:

```
$pulled = $mydb->get_results($mydb->prepare($query), "ARRAY_A").
```

I know the query it self is written correctly but for some reason $pulled contains no data. Anyone have any suggestions or solutions, please and thank you.

Comment: you're using [prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) incorrectly first of all. it would help to see all of your actual code.

Comment: How am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Even when doing though: 

$pulled = $mydb->get_results($query, "ARRAY_A")

It doesn't work

Comment: It is impossible to just guess "some reason". Step over everything and examine for sanity — is query _actually_ working, is the data in _that_ database and so on.

Comment: the query actually works, did a direct query in the database and also queried the data using the php sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) and both ways work. The data is in the database.

I can see the connection being established just when querying it doesn't seem to actually get any data. BTW I am connecting to an SQL database not MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to use the global `$wpdb` variable.

`global $wbdp;`

Then set up your query. Make it a separate variable so you can output it and check for syntax errors.

`$my_query = $wpdb->prepare( /* SQL query here */ );`

Then execute the query.

`$results = $wpdb->get_results( $my_query );`

Answer (score 0):

`ARRAY_A` is a constant, not a string. Remove the quotes from it when passing it to `wpdb::get_results()` as the return type parameter.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/ for more info on what values are acceptable.